# Asp Net MVC4 BundleConfig

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to `bundleConfig` in asp.net MVC.

My script is located in `Scripts > userdefine (folder) > js.js`

Here is my code in bundleConfig

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Javascript").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/userdefine/JScript1.js"));
```

Code in html layout

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Javascript")
```

Javascript Code

```
alert("Hello");
```

**Complete Code**

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

         bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Javascript").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/userdefine/JScript1.js"));
    }
}
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function () { alert("a"); });
```

And

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Javascript")
```

But my problem is my alert is not showing upon first load of my page(view). Is there something wrong with my syntax?.

Comment: Check browser console (F12), are you getting any errors there? Also the command should be `alert("Hello");`

Comment: can you show your complete  code instead of in parts, as `alert` is part of javascript. also `Alert` should be `alert`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i'm not getting any error in console. Sorry its a type error.

Comment: Have you already registered all bundles in `Application_Start`? Check if the `script` tag containing `src="/Scripts/userdefine/JScript1.js"` file exists in view page with HTML inspector.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto sorry im really new. where can i find the Application_Start?

Comment: @KiRa In `Global.asax.cs` file, you can see `void Application_Start()` method and check if you're registered all bundles there. Also make sure you're loading jQuery first before your own script: `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto in my layout. it load first the jquery bundle and second is my JS

Comment: Since no JS errors appear in console and all necessary `@Scripts.Render` included in layout, are you already set `RegisterBundles` inside `Application_Start()` method? Sounds the problem is not originated from custom JS file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171226/discussion-between-kira-and-tetsuya-yamamoto).

Answer (score 0):

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Javascript") is your custom javascript, might be you forgot to include jquery, please add following line if you have not added in your layout page.

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

and after that load your custom script

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Javascript")
```